# How to pass choices dynamically into a django form

Tags: python, django

How can I set choices dynamically in my form ? These choices will change based on the route the user takes.

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    options = ()
    camp_dates = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=options)
```

I would like to set the choices from my view.py file so that I can set these choices dynamically.

**views.py**

```
def camp_datailed_view(request,slug):

 options = (
    ("1", "Jan"),
    ("2", "Feb"),
    )

 form = RegistrationForm()

 ##How can I pass options into the form field camp_dates as selectable choices



def register(request):

    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

     # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
     form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

     # check whether it's valid:
     if (form.is_valid()):

         return render(request,'camp_registration.html')
     else:
      print (form.errors)

      return HttpResponse("not working")``
```

Comment: More information needs to be provided before anyone can help. First of all are you getting any errors what is your current status?Moreover do you import the `option` dict to `forms.py` like `from .views import options` so that it is available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    camp_dates = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        camp_dates_choices = kwargs.pop('camp_dates_choices', ())
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['camp_dates'].choices = camp_dates_choices


form = RegistrationForm(camp_dates_choices=<DYNAMIC_VALUE>)
```

Comment: With this method form validation throws the error `Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices.

Comment: Can you show how are you passing choices? You have to pass them both times, when rendering and when validating.

Comment: I have added the register function to the post to show you the validation.

Comment: You are not passing choices to form. It should be `form = RegistrationForm(camp_dates_choices=<YOUR_CHOICES>)` and in post `form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, camp_dates_choices=<YOUR_CHOICES>)`

Comment: Worth noting form fields are shared between requests, so if you use threading or async you need to use a new MultipleChoiceField to be thread-safe: `self.fields['camp_dates'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices= camp_dates_choices)`